# Is there a way to make Eclipse 3.8 dark?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

I have to use 3.8, because of Ubuntu and Nvidia. I changed the editor theme to be dark, but the rest (project explorer, the menus, etc) are still bright white. I looked around, but every dark Eclipse plugin that I can find requires Eclipse 4+, and those won't work on mine (I tried :(   ).

I am on Ubuntu 13.04 (old because of Nvidia Nsight support). Anything I can do?

Comment: Why can't you update your Eclipse to the latest 4.x? Eclipse doesn't care about what OS version you have, it even works on really old stuff like Win XP.

Comment: Because I need to use Nvidia Nsight Eclipse edition, which by default installed on 3.8. I installed 4.4 as well, but I have absolutely no idea how to add any of the Nvidia stuff to it (if that is even possible).

Comment: Ah, I see. NSight is a custom IDE built on (an old version of) Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse prior to 4.x used native OS widgets and colors for much of its UI. To change the appearance of those things (e.g., the Explorer views, toolbars, etc) you have to update your operating system colors. To control the Eclipse-specific things (like editor colors), you can install the Eclipse Color Theme plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. I just changed my Ubuntu theme to a dark one and it looks fantastic now.

Comment: @Mewa How did you change Ubuntu theme to dark?